# How to setup FUSE for using AppImages on CentOS 7?

Tags: centos, fuse

I have noticed that FUSE is poorly documented for CentOS and I would like to run an [AppImage](http://appimage.org) on CentOS 7. I have installed all FUSE-related packages via running:

```
sudo yum install -y fuse* afuse
```

this command ran without any apparent error messages. I have ran:

```
sudo modprobe fuse
```

yet still when I try to execute an AppImage I get the error:

```
Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/probonopd/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
```

must admit the [Wiki article](https://github.com/probonopd/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE) I was directed to was rather useless to a CentOS user as it was more directed to users of Debian-based and SUSE-based distributions. I have also tried using `sudo gpasswd -a fusion809 fuse` (where fusion809 is my username) and it failed as fuse was not a group in `/etc/groups`.

Comment: Interesting! I have the same problem (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/439399/fuse-failed-to-exec-fusermount-permission-denied-on-attempt-to-run-icij-neo4) of mine). I though that the AppImage uses *its own* FUSE, so that nothing needs to be installed, but maybe I am wrong. In any acse, it does not work for me either.

Answer (score 3):

Official wiki: https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE

```
yum --enablerepo=epel -y install fuse-sshfs # install from EPEL
user="$(whoami)"
usermod -a -G fuse "$user"
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding yourself to the fuse group?

```
usermod -aG fuse $USER
```

Comment: Sure have. Sorry should have mentioned, I used gpasswd but still, I'll add to my question.

Comment: for future readers, remember that groups are evaluated when your initial session is created.  To pick up new groups you may have to log back in, maybe even restart your X session.

Answer (score 0):

You probably did not actually install all the fuse packages when you did `yum install fuse*...` as there are packages with names that do not begin with `fuse...`. In particular you probably need package `gvfs-fuse`.

Comment: I installed `gvfs-fuse` and still getting the same error message whenever I try running my AppImage. This is despite rebooting after installing `gvfs-fuse`.