# "fuse: failed to exec fusermount: Permission denied" on attempt to run ICIJ neo4j AppImage on Centos

Tags: centos, application, fuse

On Oracle Linux Server (similar to Centos/RHEL 6) I am trying to run the ICIJ Offshore Leaks neo4j AppImage ([download link](https://offshoreleaks-data.icij.org/offshoreleaks/neo4j/sw/neo4j-desktop-for-icij-1.0.0-x86_64.AppImage#_ga=2.73172435.1544198320.1524030784-466822905.1523584821)). The image has the name `neo4j-desktop-for-icij-1.0.0-x86_64.AppImage`.

After making the file executable and issuing

```
./neo4j-desktop-for-icij-1.0.0-x86_64.AppImage
```

I get the following error:

```
fuse: failed to exec fusermount: Permission denied

Cannot mount AppImage, please check your FUSE setup.
You might still be able to extract the contents of this AppImage 
if you run it with the --appimage-extract option. 
See https://github.com/AppImage/AppImageKit/wiki/FUSE 
for more information
open dir error: No such file or directory
```

Does the AppImage need an external FUSE package? I then ran as suggested

```
./neo4j-desktop-for-icij-1.0.0-x86_64.AppImage --appimage-extract
```

and this indeed extracted the content (to a sub directory `squashfs-root`). But how do I start the app now? I tried

```
./squashfs-root/AppRun
```

but this gives me

```
Desktop file is missing. Please run ./squashfs-root/AppRun from within an AppImage.
```

So how do I run/start the app? Thanks for any pointers!